# Component Constructor not being called correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

I am fairly new to react, and i am writing an application that formats a string of text to look somewhat like a Text message on IOS ( See my render function for what i mean ). Here is the code...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  Alert,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';
import SearchBar from 'react-native-search-bar';
import Group from './Group';

var data;
var title="";
var editor="";
var body="";
var number = 0;

class Document extends Component {
// Initialize the hardcoded data

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    name: ''
  };

  data="";
  title="";
  editor="";
  body="";
  number=0;

  data = props.data;

  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      var char = data[i];

      if(char == "\n"){
        number+=1;
      }else{
        if(number==0){
            title+= char;
        }

        if(number==2){
          editor+=char;
        }

        if(number>=4){
          body+=char;
        }
      }
  }
}

render() {
    return(
      <View style = {{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <Text style = {{fontSize: 16, marginBottom: 2,}}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style = {{fontSize: 14, marginBottom: 2,}}>{editor}</Text>
        <Text style = {{fontSize: 12, marginBottom: 2, color: 'grey'}}>{body}</Text>
      </View>
    )
}
}

export default Document
```

This component is a part of another component, which has other elements like a search bar, a groups section, as well as a navigation item, which i have implemented myself.

When i navigate to the view that houses this component, the component does not show. Literally nothing renders. But if i navigate off the section, and then back to it, everything renders as expected. I was wondering why this is the case?

NOTE: if i add a simple

```
<Text>Hello</Text>
```

as the only element in the view section, it renders as expected.

NOTE2: Apologies in advance for the terrible code, i've been trying everything to get this to work.

Sorry if i haven't explained this well, but any help would be massively appreciated

EDIT: Parent added

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  Alert,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import styles from './styles';
import SearchBar from 'react-native-search-bar';
import Document from './Document';
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';

var documents = [];
var number = 0;
var data = '';
var base64 = require('base-64');
var files = ["test.txt", "testTwo.txt"]

class Group extends Component {
// Initialize the hardcoded data

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    };

    this._readFile('test.txt');
}

_readFile(name){
  RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(
    '/Users/XXXXXX/XXXX/documents/' + name,
    'base64',
    4095)
  .then((ifstream) => {
    ifstream.open()
    ifstream.onData((chunk) => {
      data = chunk
    })

    ifstream.onError((err) => {
      console.log('oops', err)
    })

    ifstream.onEnd(() => {
      this._decodeData()
    })
  })
}

_writeFile(value){
  RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(
    '/Users/XXXX/XXXX/documents/testTwo.txt',
    RNFetchBlob.base64.encode(value),
    'base64')
  .then(()=>{
    console.log('success!')
  })
}

_decodeData(){
  data = base64.decode(data)
}


render(){
    return (
        <View>
        <Document data = {data}></Document>
        </View>
    )
}
}

export default Group
```

Comment: Probably props are not available at the time in constructor. Can you verify with debugging?  The most common practice is to  process data in `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentWillMount` and setState. Other way is to move the processing from constructor inside render method

Comment: i think, initially the value of props.data is blank or null, because of that its not showing the data, to verify that use `console.log(props.data)`, are you fetching that data from api ? can you show the parent component ?

Comment: @MayankShukla i have made edits :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at the second code but I have a guess from the first sample what the issue is. *title* *editor* and *body* are not defined. Probably a scoping issue.

I think you should define those variables in the constructor like this.title = 'stuff' then refer to them as {this.title} in the render call.